# How is the path identified in Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features for softwares installed

Tags: windows-8.1, control-panel

I am unable to find a software Open office in my Windows 8.1 machine so i tried the search side bar and it is instead showing the URL for the software in place of the .exe file. So I next try in control panel where I am able to see the software installed as well as the path where it was installed. Now when I look-up the path given in Control panel I am not finding the folder as given under the Control Panel.

Why is control panel showing wrong information about the path installed and if at all the software is updated then it may have replaced the path or modified still the modified path has to be updated then why it's not reflecting the same.

What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in control panel is just some registry keys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\xxxx

For "software installed locations", its *InstallLocation* key, however it's not necessarily to be correct or updated, or it can be completely missing since this key is for cosmetic purpose only.

If you want to find the exe file, you can just launch the exe, and then find the exe in task manager, right click and select "open file location".